# docker build running out of memory, but plenty of memory seems to be available

Tags: docker

I'm building an elixir/phoenix application using a docker container.
This has been working for some time now, but recently it stopped working, with the error always being associated with a lack of memory.

For instance, the most frequent point of failure is during the `mix compile` task of Elixir (the most time heavy task in the Dockerfile), which crashes with the error:

```
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 147852528 bytes of memory (of type "old_heap").

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Sometimes it might be able to get through that step, but will again fail at a later step, like `brunch build` which compiles the frontend code. Sometimes it just fails at some other step with no specific error message, just saying:

```
Killed
```

While this is happening, I can easily check `htop` and see that I'm using 3 or 4GB of RAM, out of 16GB total, so there's no lack of physical RAM at all.

After some digging, I found that `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1` could help, but no luck there either.

The exact same build runs fine on my other computer, which runs Arch Linux, while this one runs Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Docker version?

Comment: 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be. I already tried reinstalling it from scratch with apt-get. No luck there either

Comment: Can you please run this meanwhile the container keeps running? `docker stats` , grab the memory info from there